# Count of the string in all variables using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset contains a drug list. I want to get the count of drug in all variables. Kindly suggest some code to implement the below sample dataset as mentioned format.

```
Drug1  Drug2  Drug3
aa     cc     rr
bb     rr     bb
dd     rr     aa
```

Expected result as

```
aa 2
bb 2
cc 1
dd 1
rr 3
```

Comment: Maybe `as.data.frame(table(unlist(data)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using `gather` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(
  Drug1 = c("aa", "cc", "rr"),
  Drug2 = c("bb", "rr", "bb"),
  Drug3 = c("dd", "rr", "aa")
)
b <- a %>% gather(., key = "drugs", value = "drug_name", Drug1, Drug2, Drug3)
table(b$drug_name)
aa bb cc dd rr 
 2  2  1  1  3
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion it works well for the sample dataset but I have 25000 drug names and I cannot insert all of them kindly suggest another way

Comment: @SathishJay Do you have 25000 variables i.e., Drug1, Drug2,... Drug25000 ? or 25000 like aa bb rr...? you do not need to mention all the drug names.  Only the variables names are needed to be inserted for the gather() function

Answer (score 0):

Here a more general solution for your problem using the `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(
  Drug1 = c("aa", "cc", "rr"),
  Drug2 = c("bb", "rr", "bb"),
  Drug3 = c("dd", "rr", "aa"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

b <- a %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  count(value)
b
```

Thanks to @zx8754 for the edit suggestion, previous code was `a %>% gather() %>% pull(value) %>% table()`

Comment: Once in tidyverse, stay there: `a %>% gather() %>% count(value)`